# LinkedInApi class with scope

Tags: scribe

I am trying out `LinkedInExampleWithScopes.java` example from `scribe-java`.
 However, it errors out on .`provider(LinkedInApi.withScopes("foo", "bar", "baz")).`

withScopes() is not recognized as part of scribe-1.3.3.jar.

Please advise which scribe-java version is the `withScopes()` included in.

Comment: I believe this the updated LinkedInApi class should be part of scribe 1.3.4. However, I do not find version 1.3.4 in maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but 'scibe-1.3.5.jar' works well. Try it.

Download link: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scribe/scribe/1.3.5